# MVC ExternalSignInAsync from Twitter slow response time?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

In an MVC5 application with Twitter authentication enabled, I've noticed very long response times from Twitter. Any other site I've worked on (not MVC5) only takes around 2 seconds, whereas this is taking over 14. It should be noted this is a Twitter user already authenticated in the system and already logged into Twitter.

The bulk of the problem is in `Account/ExternalLoginCallback(...)` on the below line:

```
var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);
```

You can see the Fiddler timeline here: [Timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/628kN.png)

[image]

That particular await call takes roughly 6 seconds, and I can't understand why. It appears both on my local and production.

Has anyone else experienced this? I can't seem to find anything on this while searching.

Comment: Bueller? Not even a bounty helped :(